# UILabel fixed width / fixed height get text number

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone App that read an XML file on the web. I must put the readed string in many labels ,the labels size is fixed. so, i want to know the labels contain string length of the fixed size.

Just like this I have a UILabel the size of the label is 320x480. now i have a very very long string maybe it's length is 10000. i want to know how many characters the label can contain. 100 or 200 or 300.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your labels to cut string on overflow, use:

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation; // see other possible values, for different truncations
```

If you want your labels to reduce font size on overflow automatically, use:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 10.0f; // minimum font size in font points, that can be used
```

If you want to know, what size does text needs with label settings:

```
CGSize limitSize = label.frame.size;
limitSize.height = 30000.0f;
CGSize countedSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:limitSize];
```

Comment: label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;   how to get the label show text 's length

Comment: do you mean length in characters?